# Why Jsoup can`t get information in JIRA

Tags: jsoup

I am using jsoup1.11.3 to fectch information on the link [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3151](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3151#). I try to get all the names of programmers here, but I fail. Why I can get some other informations like the created time by `Element create = doc.select("span#created-val").first().selectFirst("time");` but when I try to get the discussers list by

```
Element users = doc.select("div#issue_actions_container").first();
```

only get an null exception? I already see a div named “issue_actions_container” in the html of my Chrome.